# How to write this Regex

Tags: regex

HTML:

```
<dt>
    <a href="#profile-experience" >Past</a>
</dt>
<dd>
    <ul class="past">
        <li>
            President, CEO &amp; Founder <span class="at">at</span> China Connection
        </li>
        <li>
            Professional Speaker and Trainer <span class="at">at</span> Edgemont Enterprises
        </li>
        <li>
            Nurse &amp; Clinic Manager <span class="at">at</span> <span>USAF</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</dd>​​​​​
```

I want match the `<li>` node.
I write the Regex:

```
<dt>.+?Past+?</dt>\s+?<dd>\s+?<ul class=""past"">\s+?(?:<li>\s*?([\W\w]+?)+?\s*?</li>)+\s+?</ul>
```

In fact they do not work.

Comment: please specify briefly what you want to do exactly?

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

If you really have to do it, you should please reformat your code and reduce problem a bit.

Comment: ....I's just string....in .Net/C#....

Comment: Even if the input is a string or a stream the regex for html is generally a bad idea. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a regular expression to match an html document. It is better to parse it as a DOM tree using a simple state machine instead.

I'm assuming you're trying to get html list items. Since you're not specifying what language you use here's a little pseudo code to get you going:

**Pseudo code:**

```
while (iterating through the text)

    if (<li> matched)

        find position to </li>
        put the substring between <li> to </li> to a variable
```

There are of course numerous third-party libraries that do this sort of thing. Depending on your development environment, you might have a function that does this already (e.g. javascript).

Answer (score 2):

No not parse HTML using a regex like it's just a big pile of text. Using a DOM parser is a proper way.

Answer (score 2):

[Don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) use regular expressions to parse HTML...

Answer (score 1):

Which language do you use?

If you use Python, you should try lxml: http://lxml.de. With lxml, you can search for the node with tag **ul** and class "past". You then retrieve its children, which are **li**, and get text of those nodes.

Comment: Ok. You should do 2 steps. First, you extract the text inside tags **ul**. Then, you extract **li**. If you use Python, the code is here: http://pastebin.com/HesVF7zJ

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to extract from or manipulate this HTML, xPath, xsl, or CSS selectors in jQuery might be easier and more maintainable than a regex.  What exactly is your goal and in what framework are you operating?

Answer (score -1):

please learn to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this sort of thing

Comment: I don't see any suggestion in that question that JavaScript is being used, and even if there was, "use jQuery" is a rubbish answer which would need to be more specific.

Comment: hmmmm .. rubbish eh ? .. fascinating

Comment: "My engine is giving off steam!" "Use a spanner".

Comment: Please -- you are kidding me. he asked exactly 'I want match the <li> node.' .. that's precisely what jQuery is designed to do . . match nodes. Look at all the other answers indicating he should process the DOM rather than use a regex. What's jQuery designed for eh???